# Getting different values from view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two tables and a view for them.
Having inline query

```
select * from View_tbl where sector = '04'
```

but when i creates stored procedure for this

```
create proc spTest
@sector varchar(2)
as
select * from View_tbl where sector = @sector
```

both returns dataset with different values.
SP Returns those columns too which are in Main tbl but not in view.

Any suggestions please

Comment: How are you calling the procedure, and with what value for `@sector`?

Comment: i am passing same value in sp i.e. '04'

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  There has to be something else at work.

Comment: Can you confirm that everything is in the `dbo` schema, and no other schemas have objects with the same names?

Comment: You're going to have to do more to create a working reproduction of this issue - I could see there potentially being differences in the rows being returned, if `ANSI_NULLS` were at play between the straight connection and the stored proc, but not for columns.

Comment: Can you please post sample data that causes the issue in your DB, so we can attempt to recreate the problem?

Comment: Seems like a pretty good reason not to use `SELECT *` and to explicitly define the columns you want to return in views and stored procedures!

Comment: @N West: The data constellation is irrelevant. If the query is returning a different set of columns then there is clearly something wrong with the compiled metdata.

Comment: @njr the OP is not clear. "both returns dataset with different values" sounds to me that the data is different.

Answer (score 1):

If the definition of your view has changed, you may need to recompile the stored procedure.

When you use `select *` in a stored procedure, this will get compiled down to an explicit list of columns. Subsequent changes to the view definition may not be reflected in the definition of the sp (depending on a few other factors and the version of SQL Server).

In general, I try to avoid `select *` in stored procedures and code the list of columns explicitly. This avoids the dependency on recompilation.

```
create proc spTest
    @sector varchar(2)
as
    select
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
from
    View_tbl
where
    sector = @sector
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have the SP in two places by accident (check Master) and it executing the SP in the wrong database maybe an old version of your sp is laying around...Maybe fully qualify your tables with Database as sort term test.